# remove duplicates from table except one and others

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have to remove duplicates from tables but i am facing difficulties in which i dont want to delete other rows in table and also want 1 copy of duplicates, it has Car info and duplicates for RegistrationNo,EngineNo and ChasisNo. 
For example

```
     RegNo        EngineNo      ChasisNo
     12345        456789          5678   <--- not delete this
     12345        456789          5678   <--- delete this 
     12345        456789          5678   <--- delete this 
     34590        987643          2557   <--- not delete this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a SQL query such as the following?

```
SELECT
  RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo
FROM aTable
GROUP BY
  RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo
```

You can try it out for yourself at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa0aab/3 . I have a feeling your question is more complicated though and you need to add some more details.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use temp table to store the distinct values then delete everything and insert the temporary.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (RegNo CHAR(20),EngineNoCHAR(20),ChasisNo  CHAR(20))

INSERT INTO t
SELECT DISTINCT RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo FROM aTable

DELETE * FROM aTable

INSERT INTO aTable
SELECT * FROM t
```

Comment: thank you for your consideration ,i also want to save other rows too that are not distinct.

Comment: if there are 3 duplicate records then i want to save 1 and delete others 2, and remaining non distinct records remains same.

Comment: @Prince this is going to produce exactly the result, `INSERT INTO t
SELECT DISTINCT RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo FROM aTable` will select only records that have unique values so no duplicates - one of each.

Comment: yes it is true but what for the other columns in table it will only save three columns RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo i have other columns too that i want to save.

Comment: Then add those additional columns to temp table.

Comment: no INSERT INTO t
SELECT DISTINCT RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo FROM aTable this querry has three colums in select then how can it insert the remaining columns, the rest of the columns will remain null by doing this

Comment: Heres example. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (RegNo CHAR(20),EngineNoCHAR(20),ChasisNo  CHAR(20), column1 CHAR(20), anotherOne CHAR(20))

INSERT INTO t
SELECT DISTINCT RegNo, EngineNo, ChasisNo, column1, anotherOne FROM aTable`

Comment: this will select all distinct columns, i want only RegNo,EngineNo,ChasisNo to be distinct, and remaning values can be duplicate like colour,status,region,district.